# Delete confirmation - pass data from html when modal popup is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, modal-dialog

I have a delete confirmation popup which is opened on click of delete link.

My HTML:

```
<div id="deleteModal">
        <p>Are you sure ? </p>
 </div>

<ul data-bind="foreach: activList">
<li class="icn add" data-bind="click: function () { $root.deleteFileAsset('Image', $data); }">
<a data-bind="click: function () { $root.deleteImage('Image', $data); }">
<img src="../../CSS/images/DeleteCross.png" />
</a>
<b data-bind="text: title"></b>
</li>
</ul>
```

In my JS file (as soon as I click on delete, the below method is called):

```
var _deleteImage = function (koList, data) {
        window.event.cancelBubble = true;
        $('#deleteModal').dialog("open");
    }

//Modal popup is opened with the below code which is in ready function
//Ready Function//
$('#deleteModal').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 628.73,
            height: 328.38,
            buttons: {
                'Submit': function () {
                    _deleteFile(koList, data);
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

//This function is called in the submit click of modal popup
_deleteFile(koList, data)
{
 // code for deletion goes here
}
```

Now what happens here is,

1. The popup is opened when clicked on delete.
2. In the popup when I click on submit, it throws error: `koList is úndefined'`.

I need the data and KoList to be passed on confirmation of delete click. Because that particular data is used in delete method.

Comment: I don't think that knockoutJS has something to do with your issue.
koList and data are local variables that's why koList is undefined in submit.
You can use hidden inputs to store your values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store somewhere the data you want to pass, as `koList` and `data` variables are local.

You could try adding this line in `_deleteImage` which uses jQuery to store the data on the DOM node of the modal:

```
$('#deleteModal').data('_tmpData', { koList: koList, data: data });
```

and modify submit callback:

```
function () {
var tmpData = $(this).data('_tmpData');
_deleteFile(tmpData.koList, tmpData.data);
$(this).dialog("close");
}
```